# Is it possible to bevel vertices in a plane?

Tags: modeling

I am making a victorian style chair, and am now working on the upholstery, and am trying to get the classic attachment button depression shape. I have the basic shape blocked out, but I can't figure out how to make the shape on it.

Here is what I want:

[image]

I have just the vertice now, I want to do something like a bevel and end up with the square. It seems there should be an easy way to do this, does anybody know one?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19241/model-upholstery-with-buttons/19260#19260

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can bevel vertices using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> shortcut. Dragging the mouse will change bevel depth, and scrolling middle mouse button will change the amount of segments.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the bevel modifier instead, and activate the 'Only Vertices' check. Control size with Width.

Comment: you do realize that Ctrl+Shift+B is a shortcut for bevel with vertices Only activated !? ( so this is the same as the other answer )

Comment: @Chebhou It isn't. The end result will be the same (at least if you apply the modifier), but Ctrl+Shift+B doesn't add a modifier.

Comment: @jasperge ah ! you're right