# How to model stiches on a chair

Tags: modeling

I'm modelling a chair in Blender from a reference photo. The problem is that the stitches on the chair are not the right shape. I beveled the edges that represent the stitchings and extruded twice, first inward and then outward. But after applying the subsurf modifier, it doesn't look like the reference photo. Please suggest any way to do this. I'm just a beginner to Blender.
[image: chair reference]

[image: Model screenshot]

[image: mesh closeup]

[image: rendered image]

[image: reference]

Comment: Please be more specific.  I suggest you provide close up view of the mesh for the stitches and a close up of the rendered stitches.  Include an image of the stitch image you feel is suited to your artistic needs.

Comment: I wouldn't model them.. you can just solve it with a  normal map.

Comment: Possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19241/model-upholstery-with-buttons

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do what you wish to do is to use a texture, and a normal map. If you still really want to model them you can use an array modifier and a curve modifier. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please add some explanation of the workflow. Telling what to do may suffice for some, while others will need to know not just what, but also how.

Comment: Ok do you want to actually model them or do you just want to set up a material

Comment: In short are the seams going to be clearly visible or are they just going to be a background in your final scene

Comment: Explain both methods so other users can pick the one to suit their own needs

Answer (score 1):

How to use the array path

- Pros:   higher detail better shadows
- Cons:   more time and longer renders

Start by modeling one seam

[image]

Then in the modifier shelf add an *Array* Modifier and a *Curve* modifier.
Watch a video on how both of those work they are both pretty self-explanatory and should be learnable.

Here is my setup without the modifiers

[image]

The curve should wrap around the edge of your mesh.
In your case, since you already have the chair finished select the loop of vertices that you want the seems to follow and then duplicate them and separate them from the mesh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>)

With this new object switch back to object mode and while the loop object is selected press<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and select curve from mesh...

Here is my version with the modifier stack

[image]

[image]

You may have to play around with the deformation axis until it gets to be what you want.

Finally, make sure the origin of you seam and your curve objects are at the same location.

I'll post another soon with how to do it with textures.