# How to model a round chair?

Tags: modeling

I need to model some round chairs like these ones:

[image]

[image]

I have no idea where to start, or how to do the curves or anything, I'm lost.
So, how would you do it if you had to?

Comment: So where are you stuck at? What have you got so far? Those two chairs look quite different, as it currently stands this question seems to broad for the Q&A style of site. Please edit you question to focus on specific modeling problems you may have.

Comment: About the first one, maybe [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19241/model-upholstery-with-buttons) can be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer regarding the white/orange chair.

The outer spherical shell and the base are easy enough to model. You can start with a sphere and use the Solidify modifier to give it thickness. If you rotate the sphere you can simply cut out part of the sphere to get the opening. The base can be simply modelled by extruding a circle.

The more difficult part is the cushion. I would start by box modelling the approximate shape and position of the cushion and the sculpt it into the final shape and position. You can see the cushion gently hugs the opening of the chair so that would need to be modelled/sculpted into place.

[image]

Comment: Wow thats so great! the thing is, im new in this, so i've no idea to do anything, but you make it look too easy haha ok i'll try with your answer, thanks mate
one thing, how do you do that curve on que cushion?

Comment: The cushion is an extruded cube with subsurf modifier on.