# How to model an air mattress?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I am planning to design this air mattress. Here is the picture that I want to model:

[image]

First thing that I was thinking was creating this individual cell (the puffy cell unit) from the mattress.

This is where I met an obstacle. My thought process tells me to start with a cube and refine it. It didn't quite work out and I used circle but couldn't process it to look like a cell. I am stuck for several hours. Is there a good tips or resources to come up with the cell design?

Comment: Some good ideas: [Model upholstery with buttons?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19241/model-upholstery-with-buttons/19260#19260)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could begin this way:

- Create a plane, rotate it 45° on the Z axis, cut 2 obliques:

[image]

- Bevel, extrude up, delete the bottom, mirror, extrude the joints:

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Give it an *Array* modifier on the X axis, enable its *Merge* option:

[image]

- Give it a second *Array* so that it duplicates the row on the Y axis:

[image]

- And then a third *Array*, on the Y axis again, that duplicates the first two rows:

[image]

- Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, play with the *Array* modifiers > *Merge > Distance* value so that the vertices stick to each others...

[image]

Comment: Neatly done.. a lot from a little .. I wonder what happens if you cloth and inflate.. I'll try when I get a chance :)

Comment: not sure what you mean by "if you cloth and inflate" but I look forwards to seeing what you'll do  ;)  do you mean it is supposed to be animated?

Comment: if you want to simulate a cloth physics for the whole thing, give it a Surface Deform modifier and give the surface a cloth physics