# stuck on a quilted bed top mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

Trying to create a bed pillow-top, or quilted-top mesh. I'm just beating my head against the wall on this one. It's so close, but for some reason i just can't get it to work. Essentially, I modeled the pieces of it just fine, but when trying to add a subsurface, or subdivide the faces, or loop cuts to get it to smooth out, it just goes nuts.

I need to maybe subdivide just the mesh parts around the diamond shapes? And perhaps subdivide just the diamonds to be able to round out those shapes. Ideally it would look like the photo, where the hard stitching outline around the diamond shapes defines the depression in the fabric.

[image]

Here I am using a plane and could add the thickness to the bottom later, unless there is a much better way to do this.

[image]

and here how it is currently rendering; very blocky.

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated!

here is the blend file

[blender file](https://pasteall.org/media/d/b/dbd7848e0ff3997e49236c0eae9ac5e8.blend)

Comment: maybe the normals of the faces are not on the correct side. Select in edit mode the whole object then click SHIFT+N.

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: thanks gladys, i tried, it didn't do anything. and moonbots, i added the link to the blend file in my post. thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with adding a *Subdivision Surface* modifier? https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B4oa.jpg

Comment: Blunder, thanks for the idea. I tried it but it makes the diamond sticking shapes into round stitches. The actual material though requires those diamond shaped stitches that you can see in my wireframe view. That's been the major hangup with subsurface and subdivisions so far. Your's looks good, i just need diamonds instead of round.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19241/model-upholstery-with-buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topology might not be ideal for the quilted pattern.

The diamonds (quads) are surrounded by large N-gons, and the diamonds are duplicated. Removing the duplicated vertices doesn't help.

But if you add a *Bevel* modifier limited to the diamonds vertex group and a level 1 *Subdivision Surface* modifier you get a nice quad mesh:

[image: mesh with quads]

I had no idea how you can easily edit this mesh. So I just extracted the marked "diamond" and "filler" pattern, edited and duplicated them:

[image: models for seamless pattern]

Finally, used *Array Modifiers*, and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier (level 2) to create the mesh:

[image: final mesh]

For testing, a few diamonds are raised while others are flat.

Test render with a shader:

[image: test render]

Comment: Really nice result. Is that texture image, or procedural?

Comment: Blunder, thanks! That is a great solution. I didn't quite get exactly the same results as your render (yours looks much better), but i think i got it good enough for this particular model. I really appreciate you taking the time to figure this out!

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks. It's procedural. A Wave Texture+ColorRamp for the base color and a Magic Texture+Bump node. The sides have a Displacement modifier

Comment: @AlexD You're welcome! I've forgotten to mention the *Crease* value for the edges. You can see it on the 2nd screenshot. Crease can be added in the N-panel or Shift+E.